# How to make Mypy deal with subclasses in functions as expected

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following code:

```py
from typing import Callable

MyCallable = Callable[[object], int]
MyCallableSubclass = Callable[['MyObject'], int]

def get_id(obj: object) -> int:
    return id(obj)

def get_id_subclass(obj: 'MyObject') -> int:
    return id(obj)

def run_mycallable_function_on_object(obj: object, func: MyCallable) -> int:
    return func(obj)

class MyObject(object):
    '''Object that is a direct subclass of `object`'''
    pass

my_object = MyObject()

# works just fine
run_mycallable_function_on_object(my_object, get_id)

# Does not work (it runs, but Mypy raises the following error:)
# Argument 2 to "run_mycallable_function_on_object" has incompatible type "Callable[[MyObject], int]"; expected "Callable[[object], int]"
run_mycallable_function_on_object(my_object, get_id_subclass)
```

Since `MyObject` inherits from `object`, why doesn't `MyCallableSubclass` work in every place that `MyCallable` does?

I've read a bit about the [Liskov substitution principle](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-liskov-substitution-principle/), and also consulted the [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html) about covariance and contravariance. However, even in the docs themselves, they give a very similar example where they say

> `Callable` is an example of type that behaves contravariant in types of arguments, namely `Callable[[Employee], int]` is a subtype of `Callable[[Manager], int]`.

So then why is using `Callable[[MyObject], int]` instead of `Callable[[object], int]` throwing an error in Mypy?

Overall I have two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: If you're going to downvote this question, please let me know how to improve it. I've been on StackOverflow a while, and this seems like a very solid and clear question to me, so constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that in this specific case, I'm quite sure you could make `run_mycallable` [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) to get the correct typing too.  I.e. with 3.12 syntactic sugar: `def apply[T](obj: T, func: Callable[[T], int]): ...`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I realized the answer to my problem, so I figured I'd still ask the question and answer it to save people some time with similar questions later.

**What's going on?**

Notice that last example from the Mypy docs:

> `Callable` is an example of type that behaves contravariant in types of arguments, namely `Callable[[Employee], int]` is a subtype of `Callable[[Manager], int]`.

Here, `Manager` subclasses from `Employee`. That is, if something is expecting a function that can take in managers, it's alright if the function it gets *overgeneralizes* and can take in any employee, because it will definitely take in managers.

However, in our case, `MyObject` subclasses from `object`. So, if something is expecting a function that can take in objects, then it's not okay if the function it gets *overspecifies* and can only take in `MyObject`s.

Why? Imagine a class called `NotMyObject` that inherits from `object`, but doesn't inherit from `MyObject`. If a function should be able to take any object, it should be able to take in both `NotMyObject`s and `MyObject`s. However, the *specific* function can only take in `MyObject`s, so it won't  work for this case.

**How can I fix it?**

Mypy is correct. You need to have the more specific function (`MyCallableSubclass`) as the type, otherwise either your code could have bugs, or you are typing incorrectly.