# mypy Protocol - Does extending a Protocol not make it a 'subclass' of its 'parent' protocol?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, protocols, mypy, typing

In the following setup I define a protocol `LambdaContext`, and extend this protocol in `LogContext` by subclassing. I then define a function which takes in a LogContext as an argument. However, this function is decorated by a function called main which expects an argument of type: LambdaContext. Therefore, I am a bit confused why mypy is complaining that main is receiving a callable function with LogContext as its argument. LogContext still implements the LambdaContext Protocol:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Container, Dict, Protocol


class LambdaContext(Protocol):
    """Represents the context object passed to main_handler lambda functions"""
    get_remaining_time_in_millis: Callable[[], int]
    ...


class LogContext(LambdaContext, Protocol):
    def items(self) -> None:
        # An example function which extends LambdaContext Protocol
        ...


LambdaFunctionHandler = Callable[[LambdaContext], Any]


def main(function: LambdaFunctionHandler) -> Any:
    ...


@main
def main_handler(context: LogContext):
    ...
```

mypy results in the following error.:

```
error: Argument 1 to "main" has incompatible type "Callable[[LogContext], Any]"; expected "Callable[[LambdaContext], Any]"
```

As far as my understanding goes, The LogContext extends the LambdaContext Protocol. While `LogContext` is more specific and in this example defines an additional function `items`, it still implements LambdaContext Protocol by subclassing it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated and can hopefully clarify my understanding.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Mypy deal with subclasses in functions as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924692/how-to-make-mypy-deal-with-subclasses-in-functions-as-expected)